# AndroidX Didn't find class "android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat

Tags: android

> A/zygote: java_vm_ext.cc:534] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: JNI
>   GetStaticMethodID called with pending exception
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat" on path: DexPathList[[zip
>   file
>   "/data/app/packagename-fNlt_Hyr4Uv4lFVItkfrgg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/packagename-fNlt_Hyr4Uv4lFVItkfrgg==/lib/arm,
>   /data/app/packagename-fNlt_Hyr4Uv4lFVItkfrgg==/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a,
>   /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]

```
 @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
            MultiDex.install(this);

    }
```

Comment: This answer worked for me: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57868282/cannot-resolve-symbol-activitycompat-and-content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57868282/cannot-resolve-symbol-activitycompat-and-content)

Answer (score 3):

I've just solved an issue involving `android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat` by importing the following library instead:

`import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;`

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't add below dependency, please add it in build.gradle(Module:app)

```
dependencies {
//other dependencies
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
}
```

To know equivalent for new Androidx Artifacts from old build artifacts, please refer the below link

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate/artifact-mappings