# Cannot resolve symbol 'ActivityCompat' and 'content'

Tags: java, android, android-support-library, android-appcompat, androidx

I am new to android and was learning how to implement Location Based Services, and i encounter the following errors -

> Cannot resolve symbol 'ActivityCompat' 
>   in line  'import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;'
>
> Cannot resolve symbol 'content' 
>   in the line 'import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;'

After doing some research I found out you need to add the following to the gradle.build file `compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0'`

So I did that, But I still get the same errors. I tried clean still nothing.

How do i fix the errors?

This is the link from where i am trying to follow

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_location_based_services.htm#

This is my java file -

```
package com.example.location;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat; # error
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;    #error
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.app.Activity;

// Remaining code
```

This is my gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.location"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-compat:+'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'

    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
}
'''
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You have to use **androidx** classes:

Add the dependency:

```
implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:+"
```

and change your import:

```
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat -> import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat -> import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
```

Also remove in your `build.gradle` the support libraries dependencies:

```
//implementation 'com.android.support:support-compat:+'
//implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
//implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
```

Comment: Please look at `https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate/class-mappings`
to find classes from `android.support.v4.content` namespace and corresponding androidx classes.

Comment: Great tip. In my case, however, it creates *"Configuration `:myApp:debugRuntimeClasspath` contains AndroidX dependencies, but the `android.useAndroidX` property is not enabled, which may cause runtime issues.
Set `android.useAndroidX=true` in the `gradle.properties` file and retry."* -- but... there is no  `gradle.properties` in my Android Studio environment whatsoever! There is only `gradle-wrapper.properties` and it doesn't seem to solve the issue. Where do I place that `android.useAndroidX=true`?

Comment: Also, latest & greatest (2021.3.1.17) Android Studio doesn't like `androidx.core:core-ktx:+` and it directs to use `androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0` instead.

Comment: @WebViewer just create a file `gradle.properties` in the root folder and put `android.useAndroidX=true` inside this file.

Answer (score 9):

remove this

```
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat; # error
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;    #error
```

and add line as below because you are using `androidx`

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
```

or after just removing above two lines just click `alt+enter` on `AppCompatActivity`

Comment: in androidx it not supports v4 or other versions so you need to import packages of 'androidx'

Answer (score 4):

For react-native

Run command in the project folder.

```
npx jetify
```

Answer (score 3):

this is working on my side for **AndroidX**

## build.gradle

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
```

}

## LocationActivity

```
package com.example.location;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using androidx, you have to add this line.

```
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
```